# Getting a List from Coroutines

Tags: list, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, deferred

I try to make a method that would get a list of movies from database using coroutine and would return me that list.
But as you know coroutine returns Deferred, not a list, so I have a problem here.

```
    suspend fun getMovieList(): List<MovieLocalModel>{
        val list = viewModelScope.async {
            dbRepository.getMovie().toList()
        }
        return list
    }
```

How can I convert Deferred List<MovieLocalModel to List<MovieLocalModel?

Or is there a method to get a list from LiveData?

Answer (score 1):

To get an object from `Deffered` you can use [`await`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/await.html) method:

```
suspend fun getMovieList(): List<MovieLocalModel>{
    val list = viewModelScope.async {
        dbRepository.getMovie().toList()
    }
    return list.await()
}
```

If you use `LiveData` you can get an object using [`value`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#getValue()) property:

```
val list = livaDataObj.value
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a reason this fetch needs to specifically be done in the `viewModelScope`, which is likely the case since it is only fetching something (not saving something), you can simplify this by calling the function directly.

```
suspend fun getMovieList(): List<MovieLocalModel> =
    dbRepository.getMovie().toList()
```